# How to add an external CSS file an already defined HTML in iText 7

Tags: html, itext7

I'm getting my html from an external service.

I want to add a CSS file to it.

I haven't found any information about how can I set an external CSS that is not defined in the HTML and have `convertToPdf` apply these styles.

Something like CSSResolver of iText5.

Comment: Tried to clarify your question but you need to do some more work to help people be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to link it in head section of your html file 
add: link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="PATHTOCSSHERE"> .   <----
:dont forget to put the path to the css file

Comment: Thanks, @d3fco. So, If I'm not who build the html, I need to parse the HTML of some way to get the "head" element and then add the link to CSS, right?

Comment: @ANAYELIBARRIENTOS, right.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeySubach